# NullPointerException with zookeepers getZookeeperClusterKey

Tags: hadoop, osgi, hbase, apache-zookeeper

When connecting to HBase, the following message occurs:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWrapper.getZookeeperClusterKey(ZooKeeperWrapper.java:956)
```

There seems to be a problem in the configuration. I'm not using an xml-file for configuration, but do this in my code.
For the record, this is the configuration part of my code:

```
usersTable = new HTable(config, "users");
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "student-serv002.test");
```

I'm running this from an OSGi application using Spring DM.

EDIT:

the source code around line 956 is the following:

```
public static String getZookeeperClusterKey(Configuration conf, String name) {
954     String quorum = conf.get(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM.replaceAll(
955         "[\\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]", ""));
956     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(quorum);
957     builder.append(":");
958     builder.append(conf.get(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_ZNODE_PARENT));
959     if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
960       builder.append(",");
961       builder.append(name);
962     }
963     return builder.toString();
964   }
```

Obviously the value for quorum does not get read. Using the same code in a regular, non-OSGi application was not a problem however.

EDIT: using a different way of supplying the configuration seems to have had an effect. I now get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$ClientZKWatcher.getZooKeeperWrapper(HConnectionManager.java:231)
```

Looking into the source right now.

Comment: So can we see the general environs of ZooKeeperWrapper.java line 956?

Comment: Since you are not using the XML file, try also adding the configuration for client port: config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181") or whatever port your zookeper is using (specify it as a string though)